# TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to use the Tensorflow and TFLearn libraries in my Python 3.5 code. I have installed both using `pip`. I have the following versions:

```
tensorflow 0.12.0rc0
tflearn 0.2.1
python 3.5.2
conda 4.2.13
```

However, when running some code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed.
```

From what I can tell from [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/36), this issue should be resolved already.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    agent = DQNAgent(create_mlp, n_actions, env.observation_space.shape, min_replay_size=10000, batch_size=64)
  File "agents.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.q_net = network_fn(self.s, self._n_actions)
  File "test.py", line 23, in create_mlp
    net = nn.input_data(placeholder=inputs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tflearn/layers/core.py", line 55, in input_data
    if not shape and not placeholder:
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 533, in __bool__
raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace for the error? That will enable us to pinpoint which code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is caused by the `tflearn v0.2.1` library. The way to resolve this error is by installing the newest version via `git`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn.git
```

This will install `tflearn v0.2.2`, in which this bug no longer occurs.